# Верхняя гамма функция

Tags: ruby, math

В стандартном модуле `Math` есть метод `gamma`
Где посмотреть код этой функции для модификации, или есть ли готовая верхняя гамма фунция?
Собственно, в файле `math.rb` только:

```
       def self.gamma(x)
        #This is a stub, used for indexing
       end
```

Comment: вы хотите найти [функцию от двух переменных (неполную)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9E.D0.B1.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.89.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F) найти, а не `Math.gamma()`?

Comment: Именно! 
Если не найти, то уж модифицировать `Math.gamma`

Comment: Но только с другими пределами. от z до бесконечности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В MRI (референсном Ruby, которым вы вероятнее всего и пользуетесь) она написана на С, выглядит сейчас [вот так](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/01fb6694238ba905a08b9331430d234da054cc63/math.c#L809-L892), и если изучить её код, видно, что это просто обёртка над [функцией `tgamma` из стандартной библиотеки С](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/tgamma/), и что она не реализует математику самостоятельно.

Нет, готовой верхней гамма-функции в стандартной библиотеке Ruby нет. Можно поискать в гемах. Неплохими кандидатами выглядят `rubystats` и обёртки над GNU Scientific Library (GSL). И, разумеется, можно написать самостоятельно.

Comment: очень сложно. Да, скорее всего MRI стоит, ибо не заморачивался `ruby -v` выдает `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`. Исходники от си мало беспокоят. `rubystats` поглядывал, но что то меня там пугает. и вроде как там не нашел нужного. Хорошо ,если поставить вопрос  иначе, как реализовать процесс интегрирования?

Comment: @QWD666 вычисление многих сходящихся вещей из матана строится на чём-то итеративном, что с каждым шагом цикла даёт результаты всё точнее, но в какой-то момент втыкается в потолок точности double и дальше считать нет смысла. В `rubystats` ваша функция есть, реализована через сумму "бесконечного" ряда, насколько могу судить.

Comment: Вроде похоже на правду, но к сожалению не рабочий вариант.

Comment: @QWD666 в `rubystats`-то он работает :D

Comment: То есть просто выдернув функцию она не взлетит? Странно довольно таки, ладно ставлю гем

Comment: Гем поставил, но при `n = Rubystats::SpecialMath.new` он ругается `undefined method 'new' for Rubystats::SpecialMath:Module (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @QWD666 ожидаемо. Это ж модуль. На таких не делают `new`, чаще их передают в `include` или `extend` других объектов.

Comment: Произвел другой тест, но ладно. Спасибо)
к слову, там в readme через метод new подключался

Comment: @QWD666 забавно, я даже не обратил внимания, сразу заинклюдил в объект `main` и проверил значения. Совпало.